# Meaning of "we are poised on the brink of dramatic changes"

Tags: meaning

What does "we are poised on the brink of dramatic changes" mean?

I thought it means we are calm and composed when it comes to making dramatic changes.

Answer (score 6):

It means that dramatic changes are about to happen.

[Poised](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poise): balanced, hanging 
[Brink](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brink): edge

It doesn't say anything about our state of mind or behaviour when facing dramatic changes.

Comment: I think OP was thinking of the other definition of "poised": assured, composed

Comment: @KristinaLopez ah yes, I can see where the confusion would come from.

Comment: Yes, that's what I initially thought. Like, "he is a poised young man". But I guess in this sentence, "poised" was used as in "Kate is poised to become the highest-paid supermodel in the fashion world".

Comment: @Tuna - yes, you're absolutely right. It is confusing. For the other meaning, you'd say something like "We are poised when we are on the brink of dramatic change," or even better, "We maintain our poise when we are on the brink of dramatic change," but really you'd do better to use a different word altogether, to avoid ambiguity. The line you quote is quite a familiar construction -- it leaves no doubt in the native speaker's mind.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *poised on* is an emphasized way of implying just '*positioned*' in a spatial or temporal reference or both. See:

***[poised](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poised)***
*adjective*
**1** ready, waiting, prepared, standing by, on the brink, in the wings, *all set US forces are poised for a massive air, land and sea assault.*

In the given context, there's no relevance to the basic meaning of the word *poise*, i.e.,  *assured*; *composed*. Rather, it is the idiomatic sense as explained above that applies.